# Positive effects of a Tunisia-EU free trade agreement?

Tags: supply-and-demand, gdp, economic-growth, free-trade, eu

Tunisia might be signing a free trade agreement with the EU very soon. It's called ALECA or DCFTA.

Many activists and labor unions are opposing such an agreement because it would result in losing jobs and shutting down local businesses, according to them.

Would an FTA between Tunisia and EU be beneficial for the Tunisian economy? How?

Comment: It is worth noting that there has been [an FTA in force between the EU and Tunisia since 1999](http://rtais.wto.org/UI/PublicShowRTAIDCard.aspx?rtaid=107) which covers industrial goods.  The new agreement mainly extends this to fish, agriculture and services.  The EU commissioned [an impact assessment](http://trade.ec.europa.eu/doclib/html/151923.htm) before it was negotiated (so it makes assumptions about what would be agreed, but given the power dynamic probably fairly accurate ones).  This will give you a partisan baseline view of the expected results.

Comment: @Dan Thanks! The report makes the possible benefits and losses very clear and most of labor unions' concerns were addressed. I'm starting to get a little biased towards the DCFTA right now.